# Putting a full paper after the bibliography

Tags: formatting

In [this conference](https://www.siam.org/meetings/da17/submissions.php), the submissions should be at most 10 pages long, but authors are allowed to include "a complete full version of the paper (reiterating the material in the 10-page abstract) to the submission after the bibliography".

How can I add a full paper after the bibliography of another paper? If I just copy and paste, the section numbers will be wrong. Similarly, if I add the complete paper as an appendix, the section numbers will be A, B, C... instead of 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Would concatenating two seperate PDFs into a single document (No LaTeX required) suffice?

Comment: Within LaTeX, there is the `pdfpages` package to include pages from an external document, with the `\includepdf[]{}` macro.